# Renewed my godaddy SSL certificate but when I go to my domain it still says expired

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, centos

I am running an EC2 instance on amazon with centos as my operating system.

My SSL certificate expired so I renewed it. For some reason it wasn't saying that it was renewed so I tried rekeying it. Once I did that I downloaded the new crt and chain file form godaddy uploaded to my server and updated my virtual host to point to the new files. I then restarted apache and still when I go to the domain it says that my SSL is expired.

I tried rebooting the server and still no luck.

is there something I am missing?

Comment: Check the certificate details in your browser - do you see the new one or the old one?

Comment: When I go to the domain this is what I get 
www.freemusicpromo.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate expired on 11/10/13 6:19 PM. The current time is 12/30/13 12:37 PM.

(Error code: sec_error_expired_certificate)

Comment: What is it you get? Can you post the certificate details? The browser will show it to you.

Comment: When i check the certificate on  https://www.freemusicpromo.com, the issue date is 11/11/2012. I guess you mixed up the old and new certificate files somehow. http://security.ncsa.illinois.edu/research/grid-howtos/usefulopenssl.html has a good collection of commands that allow you to see the details of your key/crt files, check them.

Comment: Is there a different place to change the my crt and key files. I changed them on the default ssh.conf that gets loaded through httpd.conf and then again in my virtual host for that domain.

Comment: Is there a third party tool I can use to check the status of my key and crt files to see if they are valif without putting them on my server. That way I could see if it's my configuration or the files I am using.

Comment: It ended up that this server was behind a load balancer with just one server so the ssl ticket was being server from the load balancer and not the server! WOW

Answer (score 2):

It ended up that this server was behind a load balancer with just one server so the ssl ticket was being server from the load balancer and not the server! WOW

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rekey it. You just need to generate a new CSR from the existing key, have it signed, and import the signed CSR the same way you did before.